# What manuscript is depicted in the HSM advertisement?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, ancient-greece

The following advertisement recently appeared in the sidebar on math.se:

[image: On the left is handwritten Greek script; on the right are the words “Does your question fit in this margin? History of Science & Math”]

Is the Greek script on the left actually from a mathematical manuscript?  What is its source?

Comment: Probably from Euclid; the topmost, right word is "method".

Comment: I think this probably belongs on [meta], but some input from others would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not a manuscript. It is a printed book.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[User plannapus](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/users/84/plannapus) [points out](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3795/what-manuscript-is-depicted-in-the-hsm-advertisement#comment7463_3797) that the proposer of the ad links to the original source, which is the first page of  Diophantus’s *Arithmetica*, specifically  the 1621 translation by [Claude Gaspard Bachet de Méziriac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Gaspard_Bachet_de_M%C3%A9ziriac).  The  right-hand side is Greek, and the left-hand side a Latin translation; the bottom seems to be the translator's commentary.

[image]

([Google Books has a scan](https://books.google.com/books?id=zF1jAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1) of the British Museum copy of the 1621 version; it matches exactly.)

Answer (score 3):

This is an allusion to Fermat's comment in his copy of Diophantus's Arithmetica, whose page I assume is reproduced in the photo:

> "*It  is  impossible  to  separate  a  cube  into  two  cubes,  or  a  biquadrate into two biquadrates, or in general any power higher than the second into powers of like degree: I have discovered a truly marvelous proof of it, but this margin is too small to contain it*".

The comment was next to the Problem II.8:"*partition a given square into two squares*", the problem of finding the Pythagorean triples, triples of integers that can serve as side lengths of a right angle triangle. Diophantus does not mention the geometric connection however, see more under [Who discovered integer triangles with one angle trisecting another?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3291/who-discovered-integer-triangles-with-one-angle-trisecting-another/3304#3304)

Comment: The author of the ad links to the original page in [a comment on meta.academia.](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/community-promotion-ads-2016#comment8431_2166)